# Add ListView content in an Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have an activity_main layout with a ListView.
I need to fill my ListView in MainActivity.

MainActivity doesn't extend ListActivity, because I use not only a ListView in my layout, I use other elements.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_top_level);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mylist);
}
```

`Item.items` returns an array which I need to add to the ListView.
How Can I do that?

I know that I have to use an ArrayAdapter. But I can't do it properly.
It works for me, but I don't understand using `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`.

```
ArrayAdapter<Item> itemsAdapter = 
    new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Item.items);
listView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question, you have two options.

1) Something really simple that'll `toString()` your `Item` objects in each row.

```
ArrayAdapter<Item> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(
    MainActivity.this, // Context
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, // An XML file for your items
    Item.items         // The Item[] array
);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

2) Define your [own adapter class with your own XML](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter)

---

If you know how to use `ListActivity`, you can still show other elements, by the way.

[Read the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html).

> if you desire, you can customize the screen layout by setting your own view layout with `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`. To do this, your own view MUST contain a `ListView` object with the id `"@android:id/list"`